# C: Optimization causes SDL_QUIT to be true?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, sdl-2

I have a strange problem which I absolutely cannot find the solution for myself. I'm compiling a program as follows:

`gcc -O2 -std=c99 -pedantic -W -Wall $(sdl2-config --cflags --libs) -lGL -o test main.c src/sdlFunc.c src/mainLoop.c src/openglFunc.c`

`-pendantic` and `-Wall` return no errors or warnings. The problem lies in this piece of code I think:

```
while (!exitProgram) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) exitProgram = 1;
        if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) exitProgram = 1;
    }

    if (kbState[SDL_SCANCODE_W] || kbState[SDL_SCANCODE_UP]) {
        rotation_x += 0.5;
    }

    if (kbState[SDL_SCANCODE_S] || kbState[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN]) {
        rotation_x -= 0.5;
    }

    if (kbState[SDL_SCANCODE_A] || kbState[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT]) {
        rotation_y += 0.5;
    }

    if (kbState[SDL_SCANCODE_D] || kbState[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT]) {
        rotation_y -= 0.5;
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(rotation_x * 0.1, rotation_y * 0.1, rotation_x * 0.2, rotation_y * 0.2);

    createCube(0.5, rotation_x, rotation_y);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(screen);
}
```

Normally this loops until I press a mouse button. But when compiled with `-O2` (or any `-O` for that matter) the program doesn't run. Gdb says program exited normally. Also if I comment the two `if` statements the program cannot quit and runs normally.

I do have to add that this loop runs in a function (in the file *src/mainLoop.c* obviously) which is called by the main.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not much help with your specific problem but you should be wary of calling your programs `test`. I've been bitten before because trying to run it instead used the shell-internal `test` command :-)

Comment: Is `exitProgram` shared between threads?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I *have* thought about that and renamed the program **Cube** and tested again but no avail. Then again, I run my programs with `./test`. That being said, I will keep this in mind and change my output to testProgram.

Comment: How do I know if I use multiple threads?? **EDIT**: I don't even know how I can create a multi threaded program...

Comment: Is `exitProgram` initialized correctly?

Comment: You sir, just reminded me that programming the whole night long is not healthy. It was just a stupid mistake I did not see. `exitProgram` was not set to 0 when initialized. `exitProgram;` was changed to: `exitProgram = 0;` and everything was fine. **EDIT**: Reply as a question so I can mark it as solved please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by sth, I forgot to initialize exitProgram correctly. I wonder why `-pendantic` and `-Wall` didn't warn me about this.

Comment: Suggestion : switch to `clang` and compile with `-weverything` : http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html